# running time in big o notation and lazy evaluation

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

```
def foo(x):
    if x > 5:
        return foo(x–1) – foo(x-1)
    else:
        return 11

def bar(a,b):
    if (b > 0):
        return bar( bar(a, b+1) , b-1 )
    else:
        return 0
```

How do I find the running time in `Big O notation` and how does lazy evaluation (not evaluating expressions until their value is needed) affect this?

Would the first one be `O(n)` due to the single recursive call and the second `O(n^2)` due to the recursive call within another recursive call? I only know how to guess based on examples that I've seen previously. :(

Comment: if this is homework. you should tag it as so

Comment: @goncalopp -- the homework tag is deprecated.  And the second one (`bar`) is `O(n*infinity)`...

Comment: @goncalopp: actually, the homework tag is deprecated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @VaughnCato I stand corrected. I wish I knew this earlier, I've used it before. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: In the first function you have **2** recursive calls. The fact that they have the same arguments does not change the fact that they are both computed. If you want a single recursive call you should do `res = foo(x-1); return res-res`(which does not have much sense, since you could compute this function in constant time).
The second function will just raise a `RuntimeError` because it immediately reaches the recursion limit.
Also lazy evaluation does not change `O` complexity, it simply does the computations in an other order(which is often useful but does not imply taking less time)

Comment: I know this question was about Big O, but would these change much for `Ω` and `Θ`? Do you pretty much just want to use the notation that gives you the most information? For example if , could you say running time is `Ω(n)` for `bar(0,0)`?

Comment: @Bakuriu: **lazy evaluation does change time complexity**. No need to evaluate `a` at all in the second method - which makes it terminates in linear time. I tried to explain this issue as an answer.

Comment: @amit I had to remove the "generally" in "lazy evaluation does not **generally** change `O` complexity" due to characters constraints. Anyway, yes it might affect big-O complexity, but in many algorithms you actually *must* evaluate everything, so you end up doing exactly the same things(maybe in a different order). As I said lazy evaluation does not imply decreasing the complexity.

Comment: @Bakuriu: But the question is **not** about general case, it is about **this** example. And as you can see - it does affect here. I also partially diagree with the "generally" - in a well written code - yes, you are correct. But in a theoretical aspect: there are [Alef0](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Aleph-0.html) (countable infinity) different algorithms that lazy evaluation WILL affect complexity, so the "power" of this set of algorithms is equivalent to the "power" of set of algorithms that lazy evaluation won't affect time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

- `foo()` is `O(2^n)` (assuming no caching optimization by interpeter).
- `bar()` is `O(infinity)` (never terminates), and `O(n)` with lazy evaluation

---

**Explanation:**

Each `foo(n)` invokes 2 calls to `f(n-1)` thus you will get the complexity function:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-2) + T(n-2) + T(n-2) = ... = 2^(n-5)*T(5)
```

(The `...` part can be formally proved using [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction))

---

The `bar(n)` is in infinite loop because assuming `b>0` - it will be recursively invoked with `b+1` - which will also satisfy the constraint `b>0`. By induction you can get that for all `b>0` there is an extra invokation of `bar()` with `b'>b` - which leads to infinite number of invokation of `bar()` - thus `O(infinity)`

---

**With lazy evaluation, the second method (`bar()`) becomes `O(n)`**.

This is because the infinite recutsion happens only to evaluate `a` - however, since `a` is never really used - there is no need to evaluate the expression for the argument `a`, and since `b` decreases every recursive call - you get `O(n)`

---

**Formal proof for `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1)` is in `O(2^n)`:**

**Base:** T(5) = CONST

**Assumption**: `T(k) <= CONST * 2^k` for each `k<n`

**Proof:**

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1) <= (assumption) <= CONST* 2^(n-1) + CONST* 2^(n-1) = 
     = CONST*2*2^(n-1)  = CONST * 2^n
```

From mathematical induction we can conclude the assumption is correct and `T(n)` is in `O(2^n)`